# XCode disable prompt to revert external changes

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, cocoapods

I have a iOS project that uses Cocoapods in XCode 4.6.

Every time I run `pod install` XCode prompts me to keep the xcode version or revert to the changes to "App-Name.xcworkspace" in the **disk**.

Now obviously every time this dialog pops-up I can click on "revert", but it's tedious and prune to errors since the terminology is confusing as "revert" in this dialog actually means to keep the version in the disk.

Is there a way to disable this prompt in XCode settings?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no way to disable the dialog that I'm aware of.

However the next version of CocoaPods (0.17) writes the workspace only when a project is added or removed, limiting the times where Xcode displays the prompt to few rare cases.

Comment: Ok thanks.
Btw is there a way to know why the question was down-voted?

Comment: I don't think so. I guess it was down-voted because it is not a programming question in the strict sense.